# Different badges in main user and meta, Reputations only for main user

Tags: support, reputation, badges

There is independence between awarded **badges** on askubuntu main user and meta user. But **reputations is same** for main user and meta user.

However, voting and accepting questions and answers on **meta user** doesn't affecting my reputations why?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64268/172297) at Meta.SE. It explains the reasoning for this.